# Scrolling marquee control fails to scroll with MediaClock set on another control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an application which shows full screen videos with a scrolling text ticker at the bottom. 
I'm using the MediaElement control to display the videos and playlisting several together, setting a play duration.

I'm setting each media duration as follows:

```
var timeline = new MediaTimeline(_playlist.PlaylistItems[_playlistPlayPosition].LocalMediaFile);
timeline.Duration = _playlist.PlaylistItems[_playlistPlayPosition].Duration;               
MediaViewPort.Clock = timeline.CreateClock(false) as MediaClock; //THIS CAUSES AN ISSUE!

if (MediaViewPort.Clock != null)
{
    MediaViewPort.Clock.Completed += Clock_Completed;
    MediaViewPort.Clock.CurrentTimeInvalidated += Clock_CurrentTimeInvalidated;
}
```

This all works perfectly fine.

I found an excellent scrolling marquee control (http://koderhack.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/content-ticker-control-in-wpf.html) which I dropped in as is. The control does not scroll.

I commented out the line

```
MediaViewPort.Clock = timeline.CreateClock(false) as MediaClock;
```

and the control started to scroll, however now my media doesn't have a duration set any more.

The control code itself is too big to post on here, I anyone would like to help it is on the URL above.

I fail to see what the Clock on my MediaElement control would have this effect on a separate control. Can anyone advise? I would prefer not to start setting timers to monitor media duration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got around the issue by launching the control in a separate chromeless window on a new thread.